# C++ Project have lib files but it gives missing *.dll error when starting

Tags: visual-c++

Hello Professional Developer Community.

I'm a `C#` and Android developer. I don't understand much from `C++`.

I have a `C++` Win32 project. I think it's written with VS 2015.
Project have two static libraries (**LuaLibDll.lib** and **LuaScriptVM.lib**)
Lib files have been added to the Linker>Input and have header files(.h).

The compilation is successful but gives me an error when starting the Win32 program.

> The program can't start because LuaLib.dll (and LuaScriptMV.dll) is
>   missing from your computer.Try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem.

Note:

> Project does not create dll(s).

These codes are added in **LuaLib.h** and **LuScriptVM.h**

```
#ifndef __linux
#ifdef LUASCRIPTVM_EXPORTS
#define _LUAVM  __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define _LUAVM  __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#else
#define _LUAVM
#endif
```

Thank you for your interest

Comment: These are most likely import libraries. They don't contain any code, just references to functions exported from a corresponding DLL. The DLL is where the actual implementation is. By linking with an import library, you take a runtime dependency on the DLL, and need to ship it with your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Project haven't dll, have only libs

Comment: Wherever you got those libraries a headers, look for DLLs that go with them. They must be around there somewhere. Those .lib files are useless on their own.

Comment: It can build without dll but not work, is that so?

Comment: Yes, that is so.

Comment: I found something about Lualib on http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/ but  There is nothing about LuaScriptVM. Moreover They are only lib and header files publishing. Interesting. Why there aren't dll. I really don't understand.

Comment: All the ZIP files [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.3.3/Windows%20Libraries/Dynamic/) appear to contain both .lib and .dll files. If you don't want a DLL dependency, it appears that [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.3.3/Windows%20Libraries/Static/) you can get static libraries (.lib files that actually contain library implementation, that you can link directly into your executable).

Comment: thanks for everything Igor, I will search your links.